# Id's repetidos em Layouts xml diferentes no Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou desenvolvendo app e notei que eu posso colocar o mesmo id em dois xmls diferente. Por exemplo:

Imagine um TextView.

No 1º Layout eu defino seu id:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewExemplo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" XML 1"
 />
```

já o 2º Layout eu defino seu id:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewExemplo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" XML 2"
 />
```

Ou seja, eu defini o mesmo ID para textViews diferentes cada um contido em um arquivo layout.xml diferente.

Eu não tenho problemas com compilação. Mas eu quero saber se há algum problema fazer desta maneira e se isto pode prejudicar o funcionamento do aplicativo de alguma forma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método [findViewById()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#findViewById(int)) apenas procura o id na hierarquia da view a que pertence, assim:

- em xml's diferentes não tem problema.
- Num mesmo xml pode usar mas deve evitar. Não pode haver repetição dentro do mesmo ViewGroup, já que o método retornará sempre e apenas o primeiro que encontrar. Tem de usar o *findViewById()* da referência ao ViewGroup onde está a View cuja referência quer obter.